# How to detect number of fingers and add double digits using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, gesture-recognition

I am new to OpenCV and image processing. I am trying to create a program that detects the number of fingers displayed in front of the camera and add them. 
After searching GitHub for a while, I found a project that detects a hand and counts the number of fingers in it.

The problem I am facing during the execution is that unless and until my background is plain, it won't show me a number. It keeps changing numbers. How can I stabilise that? As I need to add up the numbers displayed in front of the screen, I cannot store the number unless it's stable.

```
import traceback
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    try:  #an error comes if it does not find anything in window as it cannot find contour of max area
          #therefore this try error statement

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame=cv2.flip(frame,1)
        kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

        #define region of interest
        roi=frame[100:300, 100:300]


        cv2.rectangle(frame,(100,100),(300,300),(0,255,0),0)    
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)



    # define range of skin color in HSV
        lower_skin = np.array([0,20,70], dtype=np.uint8)
        upper_skin = np.array([20,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)

     #extract skin colur imagw  
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_skin, upper_skin)



    #extrapolate the hand to fill dark spots within
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations = 4)

    #blur the image
        mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(5,5),100) 

    #find contours
        contours,hierarchy= cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        print(contours)
        print(hierarchy)
   #find contour of max area(hand)
        cnt = max(contours, key = lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

    #approx the contour a little
        epsilon = 0.0005*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
        approx= cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)


    #make convex hull around hand
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

     #define area of hull and area of hand
        areahull = cv2.contourArea(hull)
        areacnt = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    #find the percentage of area not covered by hand in convex hull
        arearatio=((areahull-areacnt)/areacnt)*100

     #find the defects in convex hull with respect to hand
        hull = cv2.convexHull(approx, returnPoints=False)
        defects = cv2.convexityDefects(approx, hull)

    # l = no. of defects
        l=0

    #code for finding no. of defects due to fingers
        for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
            s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
            start = tuple(approx[s][0])
            end = tuple(approx[e][0])
            far = tuple(approx[f][0])
            pt= (100,180)


            # find length of all sides of triangle
            a = math.sqrt((end[0] - start[0])**2 + (end[1] - start[1])**2)
            b = math.sqrt((far[0] - start[0])**2 + (far[1] - start[1])**2)
            c = math.sqrt((end[0] - far[0])**2 + (end[1] - far[1])**2)
            s = (a+b+c)/2
            ar = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))

            #distance between point and convex hull
            d=(2*ar)/a

            # apply cosine rule here
            angle = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)) * 57


            # ignore angles > 90 and ignore points very close to convex hull(they generally come due to noise)
            if angle <= 90 and d>30:
                l += 1
                cv2.circle(roi, far, 3, [255,0,0], -1)

            #draw lines around hand
            cv2.line(roi,start, end, [0,255,0], 2)


        l+=1

        #print corresponding gestures which are in their ranges
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        if l==1:
            if areacnt<2000:
                cv2.putText(frame,'Put hand in the box',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
            else:
                if arearatio<12:
                    cv2.putText(frame,'0',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
                elif arearatio<17.5:
                    cv2.putText(frame,'Best of luck',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

                else:
                    cv2.putText(frame,'1',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        elif l==2:
            cv2.putText(frame,'2',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        elif l==3:

              if arearatio<27:
                    cv2.putText(frame,'3',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
              else:
                    cv2.putText(frame,'ok',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        elif l==4:
            cv2.putText(frame,'4',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        elif l==5:
            cv2.putText(frame,'5',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        elif l==6:
            cv2.putText(frame,'reposition',(0,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        else :
            cv2.putText(frame,'reposition',(10,50), font, 2, (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        #show the windows
        cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
       # break


    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

This is the complete code.
I feel that the HSV range for skin color is not accurate. I am a brown Indian and in the mask screen where it makes skin range colors to white and the rest to 1, I can see some areas in my palm are black.

Is there a way where I can add double digits by keeping a time constraint? 
For example,  when I show 5 and within 1 second, if I show 3, it should take the input as 53.

An answer with some example or demonstration would be of great help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most used way to remove jitter from data, is collecting more data and getting either the average or the most occuring data from it.

You can measure for say one second and take the number that appears the most in that. For example, if you would have 10 frames showing [5, 3, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2] fingers respectively, the output should be 5 fingers. You then add the number of fingers to the previous amount of measured fingers, show it on the screen and continue measuring.

First and foremost I think it would be a good idea to make a method which takes an image and returns the number of fingers measured. Lets call it DetectNrFingers(image). You should be able to get this easily from all the code above since you know which variable prints the number of fingers.

You want to add double digits. That's an additional problem. If you always have double digits, its easy, you can just measure 4 times total, for instance, 5,3,4,2. Then the answer would be 53 + 42. In case it's not always two digits, you can let the person hold 0 up first before a single digit, and still measure 4 times.

I normally work in C++, so making a code example is probably full of mistakes. I did some pseudo code in a kind of python style so you hopefully can follow it. So let's pseudo code:

```
//set the start time so you know how much time has passed after the first measurement
start_time = time.time() 

//this is how long you want to measure the fingers
timeToMeasure = 1000 

//initialize with a not possible number
previousAmountFingers = -1
prevCombinedFingers = -1

while(1):
  //Get the image Mat from the camera. It can be the raw feed, or it can be preprocessed depending on how you want to display it later.
  image = GetImageFromCamera() 

  listNrOfFingers.append(DetectNrFingers(image))

  elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

  if(elapsed_time > timeToMeasure)
    //this is my example above, which would return a 5 in [5, 3, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]
    amountOfFingers = numberOccuringTheMost(listNrOfFingers) 
    listNrOfFingers.Clear()

    if(previousAmountFingers != -1) //the initial value
      //combine seperate integers to one, for example, 5 and 3 -> 53
      combinedFingers = int(str(amountOfFingers) + str(previousAmountFingers))
      previousAmountFingers = -1 

      if(prevCombinedFingers != -1)
        sumFingers = combinedFingers + prevCombinedFingers
       //putText sumFingers into the image on a position you like

      prevCombinedFingers = combinedFingers
    else //only if the previous digit was not initialized yet:
      previousAmountFingers = amountOfFingers
    start_time = time.time() //reset the timer for the next round of measurements.
```

Since you need to do it real time, I get that 1 second per frame is not enough, however you can delay your calculation a bit I guess. Just print the previously calculated sum until the next one is calculated. So do show the frame more even if you have not calculated the fingers yet. Of course you can set the 1 second to be less, but you also need time to adjust your hand, so you need to show more frames than answers anyway if you want to show the hand itself as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was of great help. I'll start writing code now.

Comment: Alright, good luck. Can you accept my answer? If you have other questions on this exact problem, just post them here :)

Comment: yes, it gave me an approach to solve my problem. I'll write the code and post it as soon as possible.